# Why sending request with `withCredentials: true` and `body` will throw CORS error in Angular HttpClient?

Tags: angular, express, cookies, google-cloud-functions

My goal is to send request to a Cloud Function and the Cloud Function will response with a `Set-Cookie` header, then the browser will store the cookie.

The problem is without `withCredentials: true`, response with a `Set-Cookie` header will be ignored.

**My results:**

1. `withCredentials: true`

**expected result**:
server will send response with a `Set-Cookie` header, the browser will store the cookie.

**actual result**:
the browser will store the cookie.

2. `withCredentials: true` and `body`.

**expected result**:
server will send response with a `Set-Cookie` header, the browser will store the cookie.

**actual result**:
server throws error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/topoint-org/asia-east1/setCookie' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Angular's code

```
  private async fetchSetCookie() {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) { return; }

    const observable = this.httpClient.post(
      this.commonEnvironment.functions.setCookie.baseUrl,
      {
        data: {
          idToken: "idToken"
        }
      },
      {
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    )

    observable.subscribe(next => {
      console.log(next);
    })
  }
```

Cloud Function's code

```
/* eslint-disable max-len */
import {onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import {CookieOptions, Request, Response} from "express";

/**
 * @bug if we send the request from an angular application, the browser will not store the cookie.
 * if we send the request directly to the cloud function url, the browser will store the cookie.
 */
export const setCookie = onRequest((req, res) => {
  handleCors(req, res);
  const sessionCookie = (Math.random()* 100000000000000000).toString();

  // Set session expiration to 5 days.
  const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
  const options: CookieOptions = {
    maxAge: expiresIn,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: "none",
  };
  res.cookie("_rememberme", sessionCookie, options);
  res.send({data: "Set Cookie"});
});

const handleCors = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const origin = req.get("origin") ?? "";

  const allowedOrigins = ["https://account.topoint.org", "https://experiences.topoint.org", "https://checkout.topoint.org"];
  if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
  }

  if (process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR) {
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
  }

  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type");
    res.set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    res.status(204).send("");
    return;
  }
};
```

Comment: Do you understand cross origin restrictions in a browser?  The host you are sending the request to is apparently a cross origin (not the same origin as the web page the script is inside of) and thus the host has to grant the browser CORs permission before the request is allowed.  `withCredentials` just  means you want cookies sent with the request and has nothing to do with cross origin permission.  The host is not apparently responding to the pre-flight check appropriately in order to enable the cross origin requeset.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am a little bit understand cross origin restrictions in a browser. I am using `withCredentials: true` because I want the browser to store the `session` cookie sent by the server, without it, it will ignore the `Set-Cookie` header. Is this Cloud Function's preflight issue? I heard that I must enable something to handle preflight?

Comment: Your code is making an HTTP POST request, but your CORS only allows GET. If you have continued problems, use the CLI tool `curl`. Create an HTTP request that exactly matches your browser's two requests (OPTIONS and POST) including headers, etc. Edit your post and show the request and response. That will help to verify that the response matches what the browser requires.

Answer (score 0):

`withCredentials: true` adds a bit more security requirements to your api.

you should also set another header for CORS to allow it

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Comment: I did add it in the `handleCors`. That's why I am confused.

Comment: are you only adding these cors headers on `POST` reuest, or on "OPTIONS" as well?

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is on `OPTIONS` as well.

Comment: do you still have the same error? because it explicitly says "The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true'"

Comment: yes. I am really confused, when I remove the Request body, it works. When I add a request body, it will throw that error. I need to send data through the body.